# Basis of polynomial and matrix spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

I have some problems to deal with polynomials and matrix as vectors and basis of vector spaces, so I propose this exercise to understand what I should do, if someone would help me. Than you to all.

In $\mathbb{R_3}[t]$, the vector space of polynomials $deg(p(t)) \le 3$, consider the linear application $T$, so defined:

$a_o+a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3 \to \begin{pmatrix}
    a_o+a_1 & 2a_2 \\
    a_2-a_3 & a_0+a_1+2a_3
    \end{pmatrix}$

write the matrices associated to $T$: in the basis $\{1, t, t^2, t^3\}$ of $\mathbb{R_3}[t]$ and in the basis $M_1:$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$, $M_2:$$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$, $M_3:$$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$, $M_4:$$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$ of $M(2,2, \mathbb{R^3})$.

This is what I did:

$T(1)= 1(M_1)+0(M_2)+0(M_3)+1(M_4)$;

$T(t)= 1(M_1)+0(M_2)+0(M_3)+1(M_4)$;

$T(t^2)= 0(M_1)+2(M_2)+1(M_3)+0(M_4)$

$T(t^3)= 0(M_1)+0(M_2)-1(M_3)+2(M_4)$

$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1&0&0 \\
    0 & 0&2&0\\0&0&1&-1\\1&1&0&2
    \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, I edited my topic

Comment: What you did is just fine.